# Crash android ViewPager + camera

Tags: android, camera, android-viewpager

In my application I use `ViewPager`. I created a few blank pages. On a page preview `ViewPager` put the camera, as described in development.android.com. But when i try to run the application it fails. How to solve this problem ?

```
public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
private Camera mCamera;

public CameraPreview(Context context, Camera camera) {
    super(context);
    mCamera = camera;

    // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
    // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
    mHolder = getHolder();
    mHolder.addCallback(this);
    // deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0
    mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
}

public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // The Surface has been created, now tell the camera where to draw the preview.
    try {
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        mCamera.startPreview();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
}

public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // empty. Take care of releasing the Camera preview in your activity.
}

public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
    // If your preview can change or rotate, take care of those events here.
    // Make sure to stop the preview before resizing or reformatting it.

    if (mHolder.getSurface() == null){
      // preview surface does not exist
      return;
    }

    // stop preview before making changes
    try {
        mCamera.stopPreview();
    } catch (Exception e){
      // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
    }

    // set preview size and make any resize, rotate or
    // reformatting changes here

    // start preview with new settings
    try {
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
        mCamera.startPreview();

    } catch (Exception e){
    }
}
}
```

Main Activity:

```
public class CamActivity extends Activity {
private List<View> mPages;
    private View mPage1;
    private View mPage2;
    private View mPage3;

    private Camera mCamera;
    private CameraPreview mPreview;
    private FrameLayout preview;

    private ViewPager mPager;
    private TitlePageIndicator mTitleIndicator;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.main);

       initUi();

       mCamera = getCameraInstance();

       mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera);


   }


   public static Camera getCameraInstance(){
       Camera c = null;
       try {
           c = Camera.open(); // attempt to get a Camera instance
       }
       catch (Exception e){
           // Camera is not available (in use or does not exist)
       }
       return c; // returns null if camera is unavailable
   }

   private void initUi() {
       LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
       mPages = new ArrayList<View>();

       mPage1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.page1, null);
       mPage1.setTag(getString(R.string.capture));

       mPage2 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.page2, null);
       mPage2.setTag(getString(R.string.text2));

       mPage3 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.page3, null);
       mPage3.setTag(getString(R.string.text3));



       mPages.add(mPage1);
       mPages.add(mPage2);
       mPages.add(mPage3);

       MainPageAdapter adapter = new MainPageAdapter(mPages);
       mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
       mPager.setAdapter(adapter);
       mPager.setCurrentItem(0);

       mTitleIndicator = (TitlePageIndicator) findViewById(R.id.indicator);
       mTitleIndicator.setViewPager(mPager);
       mTitleIndicator.setCurrentItem(0);

       mTitleIndicator.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            Toast.makeText(CamActivity.this, "Changed to page " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if(position == 0) {
                preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
                preview.addView(mPreview);
            }
        }


        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        }


        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
        }
    });
}
}
```

DDMS output:

```
05-10 09:15:44.696: D/dalvikvm(1135): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 55K, 51% free 2682K/5379K,   external 1541K/1559K, paused 775ms
05-10 09:15:47.746: D/gralloc_goldfish(1135): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
05-10 09:19:54.329: D/AndroidRuntime(1135): Shutting down VM
05-10 09:19:54.329: W/dalvikvm(1135): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb68ad4f0)
05-10 09:19:54.410: E/AndroidRuntime(1135): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-10 09:19:54.410: E/AndroidRuntime(1135): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
05-10 09:19:54.410: E/AndroidRuntime(1135):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:1976)
05-10 09:19:54.410: E/AndroidRuntime(1135):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:1871)
05-10 09:19:54.410: E/AndroidRuntime(1135):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:1828)
05-10 09:19:54.410: E/AndroidRuntime(1135):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:1808)
05-10 09:19:54.410: E/AndroidRuntime(1135):     at com.app.cam.CamActivity$1.onPageSelected(CamActivity.java:97)
05-10 09:19:54.410: E/AndroidRuntime(1135):     at com.viewpagerindicator.TitlePageIndicator.onPageSelected(TitlePageIndicator.java:709)
05-10 09:19:54.410: E/AndroidRuntime(1135):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:438)
05-10 09:19:54.410: E/AndroidRuntime(1135):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onTouchEvent(ViewPager.java:1527)
05-10 09:19:54.410: E/AndroidRuntime(1135):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3885)
05-10 09:19:54.410: E/AndroidRuntime(1135):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:903)
05-10 09:19:54.410: E/AndroidRuntime(1135):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:942)
05-10 09:19:54.410: E/AndroidRuntime(1135):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:942)
05-10 09:19:54.410: E/AndroidRuntime(1135):     at  android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:942)
05-10 09:19:54.410: E/AndroidRuntime(1135):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:942)
05-10 09:19:54.410: E/AndroidRuntime(1135):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1691)
05-10 09:19:54.410: E/AndroidRuntime(1135):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1125)
05-10 09:19:54.410: E/AndroidRuntime(1135):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2096)
05-10 09:19:54.410: E/AndroidRuntime(1135):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1675)
05-10 09:19:54.410: E/AndroidRuntime(1135):     at android.view.ViewRoot.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRoot.java:2194)
05-10 09:19:54.410: E/AndroidRuntime(1135):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1878)
05-10 09:19:54.410: E/AndroidRuntime(1135):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-10 09:19:54.410: E/AndroidRuntime(1135):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
05-10 09:19:54.410: E/AndroidRuntime(1135):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
05-10 09:19:54.410: E/AndroidRuntime(1135):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-10 09:19:54.410: E/AndroidRuntime(1135):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-10 09:19:54.410: E/AndroidRuntime(1135):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
05-10 09:19:54.410: E/AndroidRuntime(1135):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
05-10 09:19:54.410: E/AndroidRuntime(1135):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-10 09:20:02.030: I/Process(1135): Sending signal. PID: 1135 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Pleas paste the error from DDMS.

Comment: can you tell me the exact link, from where you saw the example?

Answer (score 0):

Try by changing your calls to inflate by adding an extra parameter like this :

```
mPage1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.page1, null, false);
```

Comment: No effect, no change output DDMS.

Comment: What is the line 97 of CamActivity.java ?

Answer (score 0):

```
if(position == 0) {
     preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
     preview.addView(mPreview);
}
```

Here you're trying to add your mPreview view over and over again, and java in logcat obviously says that you cannot do that...

So try removing it before trying to add it again:

```
if(position == 0) {
     preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
     if(preview.getChildCount() > 0)
         preview.removeAllViews();
     preview.addView(mPreview);

}
```